# How to show YouTube browsing in my android app?

Tags: android, youtube, android-youtube-api

This is my android app :

My media player can play YouTube videos if we give HTTP URL. So I can launch YouTube app on a button Click. It's working fine.

Requirement:

After user tapping on video, I want to close that YouTube app and get the downloadable URL of that video. How can I do that? Is there any tutorials for that? If this is not possible kindly suggest me possible ways. Thank You.

Comment: What is your question? elaborate more.

Comment: @SimplePlan: Can i show only youtube search results in my app, withouy playback

Answer (score 2):

### [YouTube Android Player API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/)

The YouTube Android Player API enables you to incorporate video playback functionality into your Android applications. The API defines methods for loading and playing YouTube videos (and playlists) and for customizing and controlling the video playback experience.

This page has a getting started at the end of the page which will help you.